# TypeError: this._url is undefined at Dojo FilteringSelect onChange callback

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I keep getting following error: `TypeError: this._url is undefined` at the callback of a Dojo FilteringSelect.

I simplified my code to this:

```
var testFeatures = [
{   "id": 1, "Adresa": "Pyšvejcova 6, Kotěhůlky"},
...
];

var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
    id: "testSelect",
    autoComplete: false,
    searchAttr: "Adresa",
    store: new Memory({ data: testFeatures }),
    onChange: this.onSelected
}, "testSelect");
filteringSelect.startup();

//end of the function, still in the same define callback

onSelected: function () {
    //custom processing
    var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(this.serviceUrl);
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.outFields = ["OBJECTID"];
    query.where = "Adresa=" + dojo.byId("testSelect").value;
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    queryTask.execute(query, this.zoomToSelected);
}

zoomToSelected: function (featureSet) {
    //custom map processing
}
```

and HTML:

```
<input id="testSelect" data-dojo-attach-point="testSelect" />
```

I have no idea where's the problem, Google found no case similar to mine. FireBug says the error occurs in init.js. Console says line 199, but the code in question (`...nction(){},onExecuteForCountComplete:function(){},onExecuteForExtentComplete:fun...`) is on line 256.

One possible cause of problems might be ArcGIS JavaScript API or Web AppBuilder - this seems not to be one of the "ArcGIS-heavy" parts of the code, but I don't know for sure. It's ArcGIS JS API 3.15 (Dojo 1.10) and Web AppBuilder for developers version 1.4.

EDIT: with help of @KenFranqueiro and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611567/1801588) I made some progress. I can't say that I fully understand the `onChange` callbacks, but I learnt to omit the parentheses while calling a named function. The `onSelected` still wasn't called, but modifying the input data to include `id` solved this. But it didn't solve the main problem...

Now the old good `TypeError: this._url is undefined` occurs at `queryTask.execute`, or between it and start of `zoomToSelected` method. The exact place where the error occurs changed to line 256, column 351, with following referenced code:

```
...e:function(a,b,c,d,f){var m=f.assembly;a=this._encode(n.mixin({},this._url.query...
```

There is a pointer at the = after "a", so the error seems to be to the right of it, trying to mixin something non-existent to something else. I have no idea what the `this` in the `init.js` should mean. Unfortunately, dojo core code is almost undebuggable without some de-obfuscation. Is this my only option, or does anybody know how to solve it?

So debugging the `init.js` wasn't so hard, it takes `QueryTask` as `this`. As far as I know, this shouldn't have a `_url` attribute. So I must have some mistake in the `queryTask` as well.

*Obsolete part of the question, archived:*

I wonder whether the problem might be caused by the `onChange` callback's argument, which I don't really understand. I've read several examples of Dojo FilteringSelect with onChange event set, like [the official one](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#codependent-filteringselect-combobox-widgets). Usually it has some argument, but I don't know what does it mean and where it gets from. In the official example it corresponds to the `div id` and nothing else. However, how is the `id` translated to a variable and even whether my assumption that it's the `id` is correct. The [detailed documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_form_FilteringSelect_onChange) is not much helpful in this case.

*Older EDIT:* `testSelect` is an object. Seems it was created implicitly with the `dom` - it's a childnode of `this.domNode`. So now I understand where it comes from, but not how to prepare another function to be called on change and why the correct syntax is what it is.

Also, I don't know where exactly is the problematic undefined `this._url` supposed to exist. In my example, `this` refers to the dijit, but I have no idea what is the scope of the part of `init.js` where the problem occurs.

I'm not sure how much related are the two subquestions (confusion in the `onChange` callback and identification of this in `init.js`), I only suppose they are symptoms of the same issue since the error is thrown at the onChange event in my code.

Comment: What is `onSelected`?  Is it a function that returns a function?  Otherwise you probably don't actually want to be *calling* it to when setting `onChange`...  For that matter, is `testSelect` even defined as a variable?

Comment: @KenFranqueiro: edited. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem at the query was caused by `this.serviceUrl` either missing as a part of wrong coontext, or being an object instead of a URL string. So the final step was to make sure the correct context is used (by [`lang/hitch`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html)) and then setting `this.serviceUrl` to be what I originally thought, one of the attributes of the object referenced as `serviceUrl` before.